# Golang Syncing Goroutines

Tags: go, ssh, concurrency, parallel-processing, goroutine

I am working on an SSH client application for configuring network devices concurrently, and I am running into issues implementing the concurrency. My program takes in a slice of hosts and a slice of config commands to send to each host. I am using a `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for all the hosts to finish being configured. This works fine for small batches of hosts, but soon the functions within my configuration goroutines start randomly failing. If I rerun the program on the failed hosts, some will succeed and again some will fail. I have to repeat this process until only the hosts with actual errors remain. It always fails either on the authentication saying `authentication failed: auth methods tried [none password]...` or the values from `sysDescr` don't get added to some `Device`s fields. It's as if when there are many hosts and goroutines running, they start returning early or something. I'm really not sure what is going on.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {
    // When there are many hosts, many calls to Dial and
    // sysDescr fail. If I rerun the program on the unsuccessful
    // hosts, nothing fails and the expected output is produced.
    var hosts []string
    cfg := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User:            "user",
        Auth:            []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password("pass")},
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
        Timeout:         10 * time.Second,
    }
    results := make(chan *result, len(hosts))

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(hosts))
    for _, host := range hosts {
        go connect(host, cfg, results, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(results)

    for res := range results {
        if res.err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, res.Err)
            continue
        }
        d := res.device
        fmt.Println(d.addr, d.hostname, d.vendor, d.os, d.model, d.version)
        d.Client.Close()
    }
}

// Device represents a network device.
type Device struct {
    *ssh.Client
    addr     string
    hostname string
    vendor   string
    os       string
    model    string
    version  string
}

// Dial establishes an ssh client connection to a remote host.
func Dial(host, port string, cfg *ssh.ClientConfig) (*Device, error) {
    // get host info in background, may take a second
    info := make(chan map[string]string)
    go func(c *Client) {
        info <- sysDescr(host)
        close(info)
    }(c)

    // establish ssh client connection to host
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", net.JoinHostPort(host, addr), cfg)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    m := <-info
    d := &Device{
        Client: client,
        addr: m["addr"],
        hostname: m["hostname"],
        vendor: m["vendor"],
        os: m["os"],
        model: m["model"],
        version: m["version"],
    }
    return d, nil
}

// sysDescr attempts to gather information about a remote host.
func sysDescr(host string) map[string]string {
    // get host info
}

// result is the result of connecting to a device.
type result struct {
    device *Device
    err    error
}

// connect establishes an ssh client connection to a host.
func connect(host string, cfg *ssh.ClientConfig, results chan<- *result, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    device, err := Dial(host, "22", cfg)
    results <- &result{device, err}
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Can I limit the number of goroutines being spawned instead of spawning a goroutine for each host?

Comment: Where does your code fail? And what does sysDescr function do? And `cfg` is accessed by multiple goroutines, I wonder adding a mutex to protect it helps. Just an idea.

Comment: @NeoWang it fails on `ssh.Dial` within my `Dial` function with the error referencing an authentication error as the reason for failure. So, I think you’re right about the `cfg` access. Is there another way than using mutexes? Maybe copying the `cfg` for each call to `connect`?

Comment: @NeoWang also, `sysDescr` uses SNMP to poll a network device’s `sysDescr.0` OID to gather information about the device.

Comment: Yes, you can also try copying `cfg` for each goroutine.

Comment: Reusing the config for multiple concurrent connections is almost certainly the issue.

Comment: @Adrian where should I create a copy of the config?

Comment: Probably in the loop where you're spawning the goroutines.

Comment: @Adrian that seems to have fixed it running it with the `-race` flag. Can you explain why concurrent access caused a data race?

Comment: Concurrent access, where any access is a write operation, is the definition of a data race.

Comment: @Adrian Ah. I was under the impression that the config was only being read from. Still have a lot to learn. Last question: Would it matter if I created the config as a value instead of a reference in my case? For example `cfg := ssh.ClientConfig{}` vs `cfg := &ssh.ClientConfig{}`.

Comment: It could help but you'd need to be careful with where you make it a reference, because `Dial` requires a pointer. It would be easy to end up creating a value but passing new pointers to the same value and having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! To answer your second question, there are many patterns in go to limit concurrency. Two of the largest are:

- [Semaphore based](http://jmoiron.net/blog/limiting-concurrency-in-go/)
- [Worker pool based](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools)

I personally prefer the worker pool variant because IMO it better helps to keep the business logic separate from the scheduling,  but both are completely valid and are present out in the wild in many many projects.

Comment: Thanks for the examples! I will look into them further.

Comment: For the worker pool method, is there an easy way to find the optimal amount of workers and jobs to create? Also, in the worker pool example you gave, can you explain why they initialize the `jobs` and `results` channels with capacity 100 if they only create 3 workers and 5 jobs? Wouldn’t both of the channels only need capacity 5, or capacity `len(jobs)`?